# Confirmation on retina display images naming convention and implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries, retina-display

So here is what I know so far, on iOS devices with retina display it will pick up retina images marked by the "@2x" suffix automatically (without any coding needed, assuming the new chrome does this too). If I am wrong on that please let me know. I will be working on a new site soon and will be trying to support retina display for the macbook pro. The only issue I have is I don't want to use @2x suffix, instead I want to use something that I define. I know I can call the image with media queries or js. The @ sign has given us some trouble in command line. Anyway, the point I want to avoid the @2x.

I want to confirm if it is ok for me to name my retina images using a different suffix and implement it with media query or js. In theory it should work just as it did before for all devices but I am not an expert on this topic so I would like some assurance.

Thank you

Comment: "assuming the new chrome does this too" Why would you assume that? It doesn't do anything of the sort.  iOS development and web development are so fundamentally different in so many ways.

Comment: @AlexWayne so what does it mean when they say chrome support retina?

Comment: It means the rendering can handle the fact that 1px on the page is 2px on the screen.  It means vector stuff like text or SVG is rendered at the maximum clarity.  But it doesn't mean there is any kind of automatic asset swapping.

Comment: As far as I can tell, "on iOS devices with retina display it will pick up retina images marked by the "@2x" suffix automatically" is only true if you're developing native iOS applications. It does not apply to web pages or web apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers don't have any "auto-magic" support for asset swapping by display DPI like iOS does.  So whatever "standards" you may think exist around this are nothing more than loose conventions.  If you want to structure your multi DPI support differently than other people do, well that's entirely up to you.

Comment: so you are confirming that use media queries or js will be fine and I can get away from the @2x suffix?

Comment: There is no system requiring this naming convention in modern browsers.  Meaning it's entirely up to you.  You could append `-retina` to your retina image filename if you like.  Or perhaps `.embiggenned` or even prepend `cromulent-` or `snazzy-style___` or `spifferroonski`.  Entirely 100% up to you.